# Classification with machine learning and a small database

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I want to create a valve detection and classification like this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VY92fqmSdfA 
to detect the positions **Open** and **close** and **intermediate** of the valve.

I have done some research and I have found some methods to resolve this problem, but i have some conditions to respect to resolve this problem :

**Condition 1 :** Use machine learning in the application, I can't use simple methods like Template matching,...

**Condition 2 :** Use a small database (Minimum 10 images by classe, maximum 40 images by classe)

**Condition 3 :** detect the position of the valve if the camera position changes, so I can't use only colors to detect the valve handle.

I want to use HOG (Histogram oriented gradient) + SVM/ANN but HOG needs a lot of images to train SVM/ANN.

I dont know if I can resolve this problem respecting this conditions?

Comment: Find a feature descriptor that works for your application and definitely use SVM instead of a NN. SVM works fine even with a small training set if you choose your training features well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, the most important thing that ML approaches need to work properly is data. So, I'd say your 1st and 2nd conditions are conflicting with each other. In addition, your 3rd condition is adding more complexity in the problem. You can solve it including more data from different angles and illumination conditions. But again, it's conflicting with condition 2.

Even so, if you'd like to follow the ML path, I'd recommend you to use a pre-trained model, a strong data augmentation and, maybe, an ensemble of models to help increase the detection. As the problem is not that hard, it should work.